# Google maps api v2 - не отображается сама карта

Tags: android

Подписала и создала apk в эклипсе (полностью протестированное приложение, готовое к выходу). И на нём перестали отображаться карты. Кнопки "+","-" есть, а вместо карты полотно молочного цвета. В чём может быть дело? Раньше всё работало просто отлично!

Comment: ключ для карт от гугла получали? А может он просрочен?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ключи, которым подписывается при отладке apk, и которым Вы подписали релиз версию - разные. Соответственно ключи для карт тоже должны быть разные.

Проверьте еще раз

В консоли гугловской должно быть 2 ключа: для отладки и для релиза, соответственно

Comment: да. с ключами запуталась :)

Comment: спасибо, кстати :)

Comment: пожалуйста. сам иногда забываю про них)